# Signature Pad Validation

Tags: validation, jquery-mobile, cordova, signature

I have a multipage form using jqm. The last two pages uses Thomas j bradleys signature pad. I use jquery validate plugin to validate each page before it moves on.

I can not get jquery validate plugin to verify if the is a signature.

This is the code I use for the validation. All this works fine just need to add the signature validation in.

```js
$("#breakinform").validate({
  rules: {
    sitename: {
       required: true,            
    },
    Address: {
      required: true,            
    },
    BreakInDate: {
      required: true,            
    },
    recafcheckbox: { 
        required: true,
    },
    sigPad: { 
      required: true,
    },
  },
  messages: {
    sitename: {
      required: "Please Enter Site Name",            
    },
    Address: {
      required: "Please Enter Address",            
    },
    BreakInDate: {
      required: "Please Enter Date",            
    },
    recafcheckbox: {
      required: "Please Confirm",            
    },
    sigPad: {
      required: "Please Sign In The Box",            
    },
  }
});
```

//break

```js
$("a.check").click(function(){
  if($("#breakinform").valid()){
  } else {
    navigator.notification.alert(
      "Please Fill In The Required Fields!",
      callBackFunctionB, // Specify a function to be called 
      'Missing Data',
      "OK" 
    );
    function callBackFunctionB(){
      console.log('ok');    
    }
    return false;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

@Hunty3000, I don't think you'll be able to use the jQuery validate plugin to validate your canvas so why not use Signature Pad's built in validation?

Here's how:
http://thomasjbradley.ca/lab/signature-pad/#accept-form

If you need more assistance, don't hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround that I used by adding the following to my "submitHandler":

```
    var result = true;
    if ($('.sigPad input.output').length)
    {   
        $('.sigPad input.output').each(function(){
            if ($(this).val().length == 0) result = false; });
    }
    if (!result ) return false;
```

and keeping signaturePad's "validateFields" option to true.